# Filter main list based on a sublist

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have written a filterList function to get a mainList and a subList1. The function is supposed to go through both lists and find which items from the main list do not exists in the subList1 and return them as subList 2.

```
public filterList(mainlist: Selectitem[], subList1: Selectitem[]) {

let mainlistCopy = mainlist;
let subList2: SelectItem[] = [];

if (subList1) {

  mainlistCopy.forEach((element) => {
    if (element.title) {
      let itemExists = subList1.find((x) => x.id ==element.id);

      if (!itemExists) {
        subList2.push(element);
      }
    }

  });
}
return subList2;
}
```

Both lists follow this model:

```
interface IList {
id?: string;
// ...
}
```

When I apply the function, it returns an empty subList2, while just subList1 is just a subset of the mainList.
Could you please help me with solving this issue?

Comment: can you give us the model of your lists (which seems to be `SelectItem`) ? What is the type of "Id" ?

Comment: Do all items have title?

Comment: The purpose is to skip those who do not have title.

Comment: your interface says `id?: string;` whereas you use `element.Id` (with capital i) in the code. Is it a typo ?

Comment: I just fixed it @Random

Comment: My answer gives a cleaner solution, but I still don't get why your solution doesn't work. It should. So can you log the content of mainList and subList1 at the beginning of the method ?

Comment: I tested your method and mine, and both work with those arrays: `let main = [{title: 'toto1', id: '1'},{title: 'toto2', id: '2'},{title: 'toto3', id: '3'},{title: 'toto4', id: '4'},{id: '5'}];` and `let sub = [{title: 'toto1', id: '1'},{title: 'toto3', id: '3'},{id: '6'}];`. So it seems your arrays don't have the expected structure...

Comment: @BanafshehKhadem You should add the answer.

Comment: @YashKrishan If by the naswer you refer to my solution for the question, I will do it after I hopefully succeed!

Comment: Did you try the solutions we posted?

Comment: yes, I am on it!

Answer (score 0):

On your current code you can try this modification:

```
let itemExists = subList1.find((x) => x.Id ==element.Id);
if(itemExists === null){
    subList2.push(element);
}
```

Alternatively:

```
if (!subList1.some((x) => x.id == element.id)) {
    subList1.push(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `filter` to achieve this:

```
public filterList(mainlist: any[], subList1: any[]) {
  // shortcut for simple cases
  if(!subList1 
          || subList1.length === 0
          || !mainlist
          || mainlist.length === 0) {
    return mainlist;
  }

  let subList2: SelectItem[] = mainlist.filter(elementMain => {
    // only keep elements which are not in subList1
    return !!elementMain.title && !subList1.find(element1 => element1.id === elementMain.id);
  });
  return subList2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the question:

```
if (!subList1 || subList1.length === 0) {
      return mainList;
    }

    let subList2: SelectItem[] = mainList.filter((element) => {
      return subList1.findIndex((item) => item.id == element.id) == -1;

    });
```